# How to show array response to a popup using php

Tags: php, ajax, json, codeigniter

I have used a ajax call to a php function in codeigniter. After getting result I need to show that in a popup in same page. Now I am not able to show as it comes in an array. Below is my codeigniter controller function. I don't think my codes are correct.

```
    public function print_details1() {
    $this->isLoggedIn();
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $response = $data['notifications'] = $this->file_model->print_view_detail($id);
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

And ajax request is this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "" + baseurl + "/file/print_details1",
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    cache: false,
    data: {id: getvalue},
    success: function(response) {

        $('#myModal2').modal('show');

    }
});
```

My popup id is myModal2. And I have given below code inside popup.

```
<?php
  foreach ($response as $notification) {

  echo $notification->publication_name; 
} ?>
```

Now getting an error while checking using firebug. "Undefined variable: response" and "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"
What is wrong with this?

Comment: You're mixing php and jquery. Completely wrong. That php in the modal will run **LONG** before the jquery ajax request does!

Comment: So any suggestion Darren?

Comment: Loop through the response in the ajax `success()` function (*which would be the `response`*) and print them to a DOM element that present in the modal, then show the modal.

Comment: You should use the javascript variable response to display the data.

Comment: But the main thing is I don't know how to print it to modal page?

Comment: @user3845839 see answer below

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing PHP and HTML/jQuery.
Below is some pseudo code to show you the right flow of how you should do this.

Lets say your modal has a div with an id like this:

```
<div id="#content"></div>
```

Now in your ajax `success()` function you want to loop through and itterate to the `#content`

```
.success(function(response){
    $.each(response, function(i, item){
       $('#content').append(item);
    });

    $('#myModal2').modal('show');
});
```

---

**REMEMBER**
The above is pseudo code, you'll have to work out the kinks by yourself, but that shows you the general flow of how you should go about it :-)

Comment: Thank. I got it :) Let me try now

Comment: <div id="content"> should be like this right? And my controller is now like this $data['notifications'] = $this->file_model->print_view_detail($id);. But not showing any output

Comment: @user3845839 You've got to print the response data from javascript. the php and jquery **can not** interact with each other. PHP is run **LONG** before the client side code does.